# Unable to decode json message in FileBeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk

I'm trying to send logs to Elasticsearch using filebeat and kafka. I'm trying to decode message string to json fields before sending the logs, however, it is not working when I view it in Kibana.

I am trying to parse the string to individual fields.

This is an sample log message:

```json
{
  "@timestamp": [
    "2023-04-28T07:27:25.682Z"
  ],
  "@version": [
    "1"
  ],
  "@version.keyword": [
    "1"
  ],
  "event.original": [
    "{\"@timestamp\":\"2023-04-28T07:27:24.678Z\",\"@metadata\":{\"beat\":\"filebeat\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"version\":\"8.7.0\"},\"message\":\"[Apr 28, 2023 00:27:24,080][INFO][pool-28-thread-6][CacheDataReaderImpl()-()] - Retrieving Cache Data of table: MYSQL_SYSTEM_PARAMS with WHERE CLAUSE: [param_id|EMAIL_INVALID_JSON] , from Instance: FMI , for Group Id: GRP_AI\",\"log\":{\"offset\":3691343,\"file\":{\"path\":\"/y/mcpdata/AIRestfulService/oltpj-cache-layer.log\"}}}"
  ],
  "event.original.keyword": [
    "{\"@timestamp\":\"2023-04-28T07:27:24.678Z\",\"@metadata\":{\"beat\":\"filebeat\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"version\":\"8.7.0\"},\"message\":\"[Apr 28, 2023 00:27:24,080][INFO][pool-28-thread-6][CacheDataReaderImpl()-()] - Retrieving Cache Data of table: MYSQL_SYSTEM_PARAMS with WHERE CLAUSE: [param_id|EMAIL_INVALID_JSON] , from Instance: FMI , for Group Id: GRP_AI\",\"log\":{\"offset\":3691343,\"file\":{\"path\":\"/y/mcpdata/AIRestfulService/oltpj-cache-layer.log\"}}}"
  ],
  "message": [
    "{\"@timestamp\":\"2023-04-28T07:27:24.678Z\",\"@metadata\":{\"beat\":\"filebeat\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"version\":\"8.7.0\"},\"message\":\"[Apr 28, 2023 00:27:24,080][INFO][pool-28-thread-6][CacheDataReaderImpl()-()] - Retrieving Cache Data of table: MYSQL_SYSTEM_PARAMS with WHERE CLAUSE: [param_id|EMAIL_INVALID_JSON] , from Instance: FMI , for Group Id: GRP_AI\",\"log\":{\"offset\":3691343,\"file\":{\"path\":\"/y/mcpdata/AIRestfulService/oltpj-cache-layer.log\"}}}"
  ],
  "message.keyword": [
    "{\"@timestamp\":\"2023-04-28T07:27:24.678Z\",\"@metadata\":{\"beat\":\"filebeat\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"version\":\"8.7.0\"},\"message\":\"[Apr 28, 2023 00:27:24,080][INFO][pool-28-thread-6][CacheDataReaderImpl()-()] - Retrieving Cache Data of table: MYSQL_SYSTEM_PARAMS with WHERE CLAUSE: [param_id|EMAIL_INVALID_JSON] , from Instance: FMI , for Group Id: GRP_AI\",\"log\":{\"offset\":3691343,\"file\":{\"path\":\"/y/mcpdata/AIRestfulService/oltpj-cache-layer.log\"}}}"
  ],
  "_id": "087CxocBQy_JTnXHdv8o",
  "_index": "applogs_ai_rest-2023-04-28",
  "_score": null
}
```

this is my filebeat config:

```yaml
filebeat.config.modules.path: /etc/filebeat/modules.d/*.yml
name: filebeat-AI-logs
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0644

filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /y/mcpdata/AIRestfulService/*.log
  multiline.pattern: '^\[\w{3} \d{1,2}, \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\]'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["@timestamp","@metadata", "host", "offset", "agent", "ecs", "input", "service", "tags"]
      ignore_missing: true
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: 5
      target: "message"
      overwrite_keys: true
      add_error_key: false
output.kafka:
  hosts: ["***.***.***.***:****"]
  topic: 'applogs_ai_rest'
  required_acks: 1
  compression: gzip
  max_message_bytes: 100000
  bulk_max_size: 2048
  flush_interval: 500ms
#output.console:
# pretty: true
```

Comment: Do your JSON line span multiple lines? Can you share a sample line from the raw `/y/mcpdata/AIRestfulService/*.log` files?

Comment: There is no json logged in the files following are some sample log lines:
`[2023-02-02 18:00:42.165][][][DEBUG][pool-28-thread-5][FetchFailedPublishRequestsTask] - No failed published profile sets found.`

Comment: Then I don't understand why you have a `decode_json_fields` processor if your logs are neither JSON lines nor contain any JSON. Filebeat reads raw text from your logs, wraps that in a JSON document and sends it to Kafka. It would be interesting to see the part that consumes your data from Kafka as well.